# How does most Forex options work? What is the most liquid or popular type of forex options?

Tags: options, option-pricing, trade

For the "mainstream" forex options for example those (in the size of bn) posted on this site: https://www.forexlive.com/orders/!/fx-option-expiries-for-thursday-july-02-at-the-10am-ny-cut-20200702

Do you know what type of forex options are posted in that site? Is it European option? American option? Barrier options? Others?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to leave a comment on the "forexlive" site asking what they posted?

Comment: This website looks very "unofficial" and unreliable. Who knows where they get this data and how. Probably not good to rely on this data for any serious use.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I did. The question here is about FX options in general. The site is just a small example to show us the volume size (in bn) of those potions.